# ¿Cómo cambiar el estado de un componente en React al hacer click fuera de él?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de **cambiar el estado** de un componente al hacer click fuera de él.
Se me ocurrió registrar un evento al hacer click en un elemento del DOM, pero no me funcionó a la hora de cambiar el estado.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```js
function Sidebar ({ state, setState }) {
  const sidebarLi = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar li');
  document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const click = e.target;
    sidebarLi.forEach(function (element) {
      if (click === element) {
        setState(true);
      } else {
        setState(false);
      }
    });
  });
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {state && (
        <div className='sidebar'>
            // Acá va más código pero no lo puedo poner porque stackoverflow me dice
            // que la publicación tiene mucho código
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: Prueba a poner un addeventlistener click al document dentro de un useeffect y toma con el event quien hizo click, si no es el elemento en cuestion pues haz lo pertinente. No olvides sanear el listener con el callback del effect

Answer (score 0):

Una forma en la que podrías lograr eso es event delegation es decir poner un event listener en window y de ahí hacer un condicional para verificar que el click esta fuera del sidebar. Algo así:

```
window.addEventListener(click, (event) => {
  const isSidebar = event.target.closest("#sidebar")
  // para que encuentre el sidebar de esta manera tendrías que incluir un ID sidebar en tu elemento contenedor
  if (isSidebar) return; // este es el condicional
  
  // aquí lo que quieres que se ejecute
} )
```